# How to create circular mask for Mat object in OpenCV / C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

My goal is to create a circular mask on a `Mat` object, so e.g. for a `Mat` looking like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

...modify it such that I obtain a **"circular shape"** of `1`s within it, so .e.g.

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I am currently using the following code:

```
typedef struct {
    double radius;
    Point center;
} Circle;

...

for (Circle c : circles) {

    // get the circle's bounding rect
    Rect boundingRect(c.center.x-c.radius, c.center.y-c.radius, c.radius*2,c.radius*2);

    // obtain the image ROI:
    Mat circleROI(stainMask_, boundingRect);
    int radius = floor(radius);
    circle(circleROI, c.center, radius, Scalar::all(1), 0);
}
```

The problem is that after my call to `circle`, there is *at most* only one field in the `circleROI` set to `1`... According to my understanding, this code should work because `circle` is supposed to use the information about the `center` and the `radius` to modify `circleROI` such that all points that are within the area of the circle should be set to `1`... does anyone have an explanation for me what I am doing wrong? Am I taking the right approach to the problem but the actual issue might be somewhere else (this is very much possible too, since I am a novice to C++ and OpenCv)?

Note that I also tried to modify the last parameter in the `circle` call (which is the *thickness of the circle outline*) to `1` and `-1`, without any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you're filling your circleROI with a coordinate of the circle in the big mat. Your circle coordinate inside the circleROI should be relative to the circleROI, which is, in your case: new_center = (c.radius, c.radius), new_radius = c.radius.

Here is a snipcode for the loop:

```
for (Circle c : circles) {

    // get the circle's bounding rect
    Rect boundingRect(c.center.x-c.radius, c.center.y-c.radius, c.radius*2+1,c.radius*2+1);

    // obtain the image ROI:
    Mat circleROI(stainMask_, boundingRect);

    //draw the circle
    circle(circleROI, Point(c.radius, c.radius), c.radius, Scalar::all(1), -1);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:   `getStructuringElement`

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html